# Validation (CSS 3.0) "text" is not a valid value for the "-webkit-background-clip" property

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

So this is my code:

```
font-size: 44px;
font-weight: 500;
background: linear-gradient(to-right, #494964, #6f6f89);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

I wanted to use the background clip property to clip the background to the text. Problem is visual studio is not recognizing the text property. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: you also need to add the non-webkit version

Comment: I tried it doesn't work. It does not seem to accept text as a valid value. I'm using visual studio community.

Comment: simply ignore the error because `text` is valid as value

Comment: The problem is unfortunately since the clip property is not working because it does not recognize the 'text' value. It skips that line and goes straight to the next one in this case '-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;' and makes the text transparent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you are setting the `background-clip` property on the parent text element i.e. `<p>` tag then you can apply the background color as a class. Please see below for a working example.

Please note your linear gradient declaration should also be written like below without the hyphen in `to-right`:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #494964, #6f6f89);
```

```css
.container p {
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font: 900 1.2em sans-serif;
}
.background-color {
  background: linear-gradient(60deg, blue, yellow, red, yellow, red);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="background-color">
    The background is clipped to the foreground text.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could also have to do with the fact that `background-clip: text` is an experimental feature, according to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip#values)

[image: MDN docs for background-clip]